# @Service Class Not Autowired in org.mapstruct.@Mapper Class

Tags: java, spring, mapstruct

I am trying to add json serialization to my SpringBoot app using MapStruct. @Mapper class uses @Service to add some "aftermapping" logic. The problem is, that this @Service class is not autowired.

This is my Mapper class:

```
@Mapper(unmappedTargetPolicy = ReportingPolicy.IGNORE, componentModel = "spring")
public abstract class InstrumentMapper {

    protected MarketDataService marketDataService; // is @Service

    @Mapping(target = "marketCode",
            expression = "java(instrument.getMarket().getCode())")
    public abstract InstrumentDto fromInstrument(Instrument instrument);

    public abstract List<InstrumentDto> fromInstruments(List<Instrument> instruments);

    @Mapping(target = "market",
            expression = "java(marketDataService.findMarketByCode(instrumentDto.getMarketCode()))")
    public abstract Instrument toInstrument(InstrumentDto instrumentDto);

    public abstract List<Instrument> toInstruments(List<InstrumentDto> instrumentDtos);

    @Autowired
    public void setMarketDataService(MarketDataService marketDataService) {
        this.marketDataService = marketDataService;
    }
}
```

When `toInstrument` method is called, application fails with NPE, trying to `marketDataService.findMarketByCode(instrumentDto.getMarketCode())`.

Hopefully, this information will be enough. Let me know if anything else is needed.

Thanks in advance!

Update:

MarketDataService class. It is added to the context through @Service annotation.

```
@Service
public class MarketDataService {

    @Autowired
    private InstrumentRepository instrumentRepository;

    public Instrument findInstrumentByCode(String code) {
        return instrumentRepository.findFirstByCode(code);
    }

    public List<InstrumentDto> getAllInstrumentDtos() {
        List<Instrument> instruments = getAllInstruments();
        List<InstrumentDto> dtos = Mappers.getMapper(InstrumentMapper.class).fromInstruments(instruments);
        return dtos;
    }

    public void updateInstrument(InstrumentDto instrumentDto) {
        Instrument instrument = findInstrumentByCode(instrumentDto.getCode());
        if (instrument == null) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Market with given code not found!");
        }
        instrumentRepository.delete(instrument);
        instrument = Mappers.getMapper(InstrumentMapper.class).toInstrument(instrumentDto);
        instrumentRepository.save(instrument);
    }
}
```

The algorithm is the following: @Controller class gets PUT request and calls MarketDataService.updateInstrument method with the body of the request (instrumentDto parameter). The latter one calls toInstrument method with the same parameter.

Comment: please add also the class and the code that calls toInstrument method

Comment: Edit your question with code that shows us how you added MarketDataService to the application context. Through Component  annotation or Bean annotation ?

Comment: What is your reason for using a setter instead of the constructor?

Comment: @PanagiotisBougioukos  Class, requesting .toInstrument added

Comment: @chrylis-cautiouslyoptimistic- tried both. This is just the latest version :)

Comment: If you have a constructor argument, it _should not be possible_ for it to be uninitialized. Note that using field injection is fragile and generally discouraged.

Comment: @chrylis-cautiouslyoptimistic- but this is an abstract class. can i create a custom constructor?

Comment: Sure you can. (The one question is whether MapStruct knows how to make a `super` call from its generated concrete class, and I'm not certain about that.)

Comment: Your mapper instance you are using isn't managed by Spring. You are doing `Mappers.getMapper(InstrumentMapper.class)` which creates one outside the scope of spring. YOu need to inject the mapper into the service (which will lead to another issue of a circular dependency).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why you have an NPE is because you are using the MapStruct `Mappers` factory for a non default component model.

The `Mappers` factory does not perform any dependency injections.

You have to inject your mapper in your `MarketDataService`. Be careful when doing that because you have a cyclic dependency.

---

In addition to that the patterns you are using in your Mapper are not really the right ones. You are using an expression when a simple `source` will do.

e.g.

```
@Mapper(unmappedTargetPolicy = ReportingPolicy.IGNORE, componentModel = "spring")
public abstract class InstrumentMapper {

    protected InstrumentRepository instrumentRepository;

    @Mapping(target = "marketCode", source = "market.code")
    public abstract InstrumentDto fromInstrument(Instrument instrument);

    public abstract List<InstrumentDto> fromInstruments(List<Instrument> instruments);

    @Mapping(target = "market", source = "marketCode")
    public abstract Instrument toInstrument(InstrumentDto instrumentDto);

    public abstract List<Instrument> toInstruments(List<InstrumentDto> instrumentDtos);

    protected Instrument findInstrumentByCode(String code) {
        return instrumentRepository.findFirstByCode(code);
    }

    @Autowired
    public void setMarketDataService(MarketDataService marketDataService) {
        this.marketDataService = marketDataService;
    }
}
```